# Правила хорошего кода в PHP. Многочисленные выборки.

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток.

Т.к. с PHP я первый год, то много не знаю. Вопрос по большей части теоретический. Представьте себе сайт. На сайте список товаров. Естественно он пролистывается по страницам, да еще и может быть с каким-то условием... и может быть еще с каким-то.

По началу, да и в силу ненадобности, ограничился переменными, выловленными с помощью GET. Но параметров больше и больше, и совать их в строку адреса не вариант. На некоторых сайтах вообще выборка бывает в сотню параметров. Тогда строка адреса вообще не вариант.

Подскажите, чем пользуетесь для передачи параметров для запроса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$_POST`, а смена страницы - добавление номера страницы в фильтр (`input:hidden`) и `submit()`
2. `$_POST` и запись фильтра в сессию. Если фильтры для разделов разные, делаем массив вида `$_SESSION['filter']['category']['property']['value']`
3. Если все цифровое, можно и в куки запиливать. Тогда у фильтра должны быть забиты все значения в одинаковом количестве, кука вида `filter_category1 = '1|14|22|15|65|1|0|2'`. При нажатии на "поиск" сохраняем куку и отправляем get-запрос, на серваке разбираем.
4. Ну и так далее. Можно вообще извратиться и в базе их хранить, но это именно изврат) Хотя иногда нужный.